# How to find optimal scores in a score database in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a database of scores (C2:C937) which range from 4000-6500. I have the records for each score (D2:D937) and the differential between the 2 (E2:E937). I am trying to find a formula to tell me which score is closest to going over 5000. I was thinking to have a formula that checks the sums of the C column values and their corresponding E column values, and then sorting by which values have the most to improve. I don't know if it's possible to make a loop of sorts in sheets (kind of like a for loop in Java).

The image below it shows a set of values as explained above. The result I would be looking for would return whichever value has the highest chance of going over 5000, that is already the closest.

[image: Piece of the dataset]

Here is a set of expected results. In this dataset, "Yanmega 4" would never be returned since it is already over 5000 in the C column. "Zangoose 1" and "Yanmega 3" would be first since they are close to going over 5000 and have enough leeway above 5000 (~400 points of leeway above it). "Zangoose 2" would be next since it has ~300 over 5000 meaning getting over 5000 should be easier than some of the others. "Zangoose 4" would be next since only 28 points need to be gained to get more than 5000, and there are 105 points of wiggle room as well. "Zangoose 3" is last since it only has 15 points of wiggle room based upon the current record.

[image: Expected Results]

Here is what I had started. The first line is convuluted and was my attempt at creating a loop. The second line has a good start I just don't know where to go from there. Both lines are unfinished.

```
=IF(IF(LARGE($C$2:$C$937,1)<5000,LARGE($C$2:$C$937,1),IF(LARGE($C$2:$C$937,2)<5000,LARGE($C$2:$C$937,2),LARGE($C$2:$C$937,3))+INDIRECT("E"&match(E954,$E$1:$E$940,0))<=5000,))
=IF(LARGE($C$2:$C$937,1)<5000,)
```

Comment: try uploading a demo with some data & the formulas you plan to use, so helping you go further on will be easy.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Apostolos55 I added some data, desired output, and some planned code. Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: @player0  I added some data, desired output, and some planned code. Hopefully that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

1st I think your logic is not correct. I would rather have Zanggose 4 as 1st, then Yanmega 3, then Zanggose 2 or Zangoose 3...
you can use a formula like:

```
=INDEX(B3:B8,MATCH( SMALL( IF($C$3:$C$8<5000,(5000-$C$3:$C$8)*100/$D$3:$D$8,100),*ROW($A$1:$A$6)* ), IF($C$3:$C$8<5000,(5000-$C$3:$C$8)*100/$D$3:$D$8,100),0),)
```

and insert the Function as Array (with ctrl+sht+enter) to as many cells as needed (paste formula in top cell, fix it, then enter as Array, then select all destination cells, press F2 to edit formula, then ectrl+sht+enter)

adjusting c3:c8 to your c928:c933 and so on, then *ROW($A$1:$A$6)* as big as you data.

Problem is that too many calls are made recursively and in large number of rows things will get very slow... You better use an extra Column with the formula

```
=IF($C$3:$C$8<5000,(5000-$C$3:$C$8)*100/$D$3:$D$8,100)
```

and then Filter/sort the data with VBA or Filters (there are excellent youtube videos on the subject, as long as company policies (if any) allow usage of VBA).